# libcrypto.so: error adding symbols: File in wrong format clang++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1

Tags: android, ssl, android-ndk, boringssl

I am trying to build `boringssl` for Android's `armeabi-v7a`. I looked at the [boringssl](https://github.com/google/boringssl/blob/master/BUILDING.md) git document and built it.

```
//termanal
cmake -DANDROID_ABI=armeabi-v7a \
-DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-21 \
-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=${ANDROID_NDK_ROOT}/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake \
-DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=1 \
-GNinja -B build

ninja -C build
```

When you run the above command in the terminal, the `boringssl/build` directory is created and `.so` and build files are created inside the directory.

I put `libcrypto.so`, `libssl.so` in `app/opensslSO/libs` in android project. Header files are placed in `app/opensslSO/include`.

I wrote `CMakeLists.txt` for library linking.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.18.1)


# OpenSSL 라이브러리 경로 설정
set(OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/opensslSO/include")
set(OPENSSL_LIBRARY_DIR "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/opensslSO/libs")

include_directories(
    ${OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR}
)

add_library(crypto SHARED IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(crypto PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${OPENSSL_LIBRARY_DIR}/libcrypto.so)

add_library(ssl SHARED IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(ssl PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${OPENSSL_LIBRARY_DIR}/libssl.so)

add_library(pki SHARED IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(pki PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${OPENSSL_LIBRARY_DIR}/libpki.so)

add_library(decrepit SHARED IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(decrepit PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${OPENSSL_LIBRARY_DIR}/libdecrepit.so)


add_library( score_printer

             # Sets the library as a shared library.
             SHARED

             # Provides a relative path to your source file(s).
             my_native_file_path
             )


target_link_libraries( native_lib
                       crypto
                       ssl
                       pki
                       decrepit
                       android
                       log
                       EGL
                       GLESv1_CM
                      )
```

I thought it would work fine, but I get an error.

```
/opensslSO/libs/libcrypto.so: error adding symbols: File in wrong format
  clang++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
  ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

Comment: By the looks of it, you're only building BoringSSL for armeabi-v7a. Have you added the necessary `abiFilters` in your gradle script so that your other native code also is built only for armeabi-v7a? Also, what is `native_lib`? Did you mean `score_printer`?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I solved the problem and left it in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Solved :**

This can be solved by building `ABI` for not only `armeabi-v7a`, but also `arm64-v8a`, `x86` and `x86_64` and setting the directories separately.

```
set(OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/opensslSO/include")
set(OPENSSL_LIBRARY_DIR "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/opensslSO/libs/${ANDROID_ABI}")

include_directories(
    ${OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR}
)

add_library(crypto SHARED IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(crypto PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${OPENSSL_LIBRARY_DIR}/libcrypto.so)


add_library(ssl SHARED IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(ssl PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${OPENSSL_LIBRARY_DIR}/libssl.so)

add_library(pki SHARED IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(pki PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${OPENSSL_LIBRARY_DIR}/libpki.so)

add_library(decrepit SHARED IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(decrepit PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${OPENSSL_LIBRARY_DIR}/libdecrepit.so)


target_link_libraries( 
                       crypto
                       ssl
                       pki
                       decrepit
                       android
                       log
                       EGL
                       GLESv1_CM
                      )
```

[image]